# Change Sharepoint online search result ranking with "Advanced Searchable Settings"

Tags: search, ranking

I want to add a higher ranking in search results for a list.

I go to site settings, site collection "Search Schema", search a managed property from this list, open "Advanced Searchable Settings", "Weight group" and select "Context 1". Saved but nothing in search results changed.

If i open the searchable settings again "Context 0" is selected again and i see no changes in the search results. Are my settings correct to change the ranking, is this a bug or should i consider another solution?

Comment: Wanted to add that I am seeing the same behavior you described, in my client's O365 tenant.

Comment: The workaround for this is a query rule without condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it's a bug, but I have always used query rules to change the ranking. Works well in every case. Very easy to control.

Comment: I try to rank the whole list results higher. There is no specific query i could match.

Comment: Then remove the condition and add your ranking rule. Or just use XRANK and content boost: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/keyword-query-language-kql-syntax-reference

Comment: I can only change the query for all searches without the query rule but this would be fine. I copied the saved search source and edit it like this

{?{searchTerms} -ContentClass=urn:content-class:SPSPeople}  (ContentTypeId:0x012000064c4c5203c44be29ab61bcfd8d3e2c8* OR ContentTypeId:0x012000c6becca3a23f4b399b07cd6e95cd14dd*  OR ContentTypeId:0x0100f12b86f19f7842edb8c72d5cac8d936c* OR ContentTypeId:0x0100BC0BF0B071F84C6AA08757218C27C8A7*) XRANK(cb=5)

The search result shows this error: We're not sure we understood your query, so the results might not be what you were looking for.

Comment: Are these content types in a specific library or site? Have you tried Authoritative Pages/Sites?

Comment: I removed the condition in the query rule and it worked. Thanks!